# Blender and three.js recent versions December 1, 2018

Tags: add-on, three.js

I am struggling with adding Blender export to three.js because my Googling is showing older tutorials on both.

My goal is to export a model from Blender to three.js or at least I think that's the correct wording. I have a .fbx file but really need to learn .json file or whatever exported from Blender.

I have tried going to the addons but three is not showing up with three.js as an option. I think it must be a directory issue.
[image]

I am using the absolute latest of both as of December 1, 2018.

Any advice? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the three.js exporter would have disappeared from the specific folder in your screenshot (did you download it from somewhere particular? was it already on your computer?) but the three.js (JSON) Blender exporter has been removed from recent versions of the three.js library.

Instead, I would suggest one of the following:

- Load your FBX (`.fbx`) file directly with THREE.FBXLoader.
- Export to glTF (`.gltf` or `.glb`) and load with THREE.GLTFLoader.

A glTF exporter is included in Blender 2.80+. For older versions of Blender, you can download the importer/exporter here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.

Per [three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models), using glTF is recommended where possible.

Comment: Ugh, why did they do that?

Comment: Why remove the JSON exporter? It was difficult to maintain and had several key bugs. glTF works very well on the web, and solved a lot of those issues, so the decision was to focus on supporting that. Both FBX and glTF were working better in three.js than JSON, so a custom format wasn't necessary. Note that the JSON format itself is still supported — just not the Blender exporter — so existing files are fine. See: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12903.

Comment: I should also clarify — this wasn't just a Blender thing. The three.js Maya and 3DS Max exporters were removed at the same time.

Comment: AHH, so I'm not trying to use a three.js add-on in Blender. Just export as normal. Phew! Thank you so much @Don McCurdy! I can now pull myself out of this rabbit hole!